# Multiple file upload issue (simple php/html)

Tags: php, file-upload

The only issue with the code below - it creates one record if no image was selected. It's not supposed to proceed the code if no one image is chosen. This method works fine with single type image form.

```
if(!empty($_FILES['gallery']['name'])) {
            for ($i=0; $i < count($_FILES['gallery']['tmp_name']); $i++) { 
            $gallery_tmp = $_FILES['gallery']['tmp_name'][$i];
            $gallery = time().$_FILES['gallery']['name'][$i];
            move_uploaded_file($gallery_tmp, "../uploads/$gallery");
            $sql = mysqli_query($database->connection, "INSERT INTO gallery (img) VALUES ('$gallery')");
            }
        }
```

HTML code is below:

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="gallery[]" class="form-control" multiple="multiple">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Update" class="">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if you don't send any images your $_FILES['gallery']['name'] is not empty, it cointain 1 element with empty name.

You could do a dirty hack by checking if first elemetn is not empty:

```
if(!empty($_FILES['gallery']['name'][0])) {
```

But you should really check if it's empty inside the loop.

Also don't trust user input by doing

```
$gallery = time().$_FILES['gallery']['name'][$i];
move_uploaded_file($gallery_tmp, "../uploads/$gallery");
```

Someone could name a file test.php and upload you code, or set in name "../../index.php and override your index.php :)

Comment: Your solution works good. I'm not sure about the security issues. I'm quite new on programming and I'm just making some projects for myself education. I do not check for any extension of the uploading files. But later I should add this functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Added condition that if image not uploaded, its record won't be inserted to database.

**Updated Code:**

```
if(!empty($_FILES['gallery']['name'])) {
    for ($i=0; $i < count($_FILES['gallery']['tmp_name']); $i++) { 
        $gallery_tmp = $_FILES['gallery']['tmp_name'][$i];
        $gallery = time().$_FILES['gallery']['name'][$i];
        $is_uploaded = move_uploaded_file($gallery_tmp, "../uploads/$gallery");

        if( $is_uploaded == TRUE ) {
            $sql = mysqli_query($database->connection, "INSERT INTO gallery (img) VALUES ('$gallery')");
        }
    }
}
```